# chrome devtools no longer displays variables inline while debugging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging an angular application. I don't know what happened, my source code used to be colored but now it's all in black and when I hover my mouse on a variable, I used to see its value, now I can't. Can anyone tell me how can I fix that?

Normally, it should be like this example
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/preview-javascript-values-inline-while-debugging

But what I have is this :

[image]

I want to display the variable's value when I hover my mouse on it.

Comment: This is a bug that will be fixed in the next update of Chrome. Meanwhile you can use Chrome Canary which is installed separately.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you provide a link to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem we downloaded Canary version of browser using Chromium 81

- [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/)
- [Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/)